# "Invalid Chain Id" on Kovan testnet

Tags: web3js, transactions, kovan, ethereumjs-tx

I'm attempting to initiate a transaction (transfer of ETH) from my main account to a test account on the Kovan Testnet, but I'm getting the error `Returned error: Invalid chain id.` from the following code:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const EthereumTx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction;

const SK = process.env.PROD ? nice try ;)
const PK = process.env.PROD ? "0x5A8721b7DE69b3538a4cC61614628f7c1A6E59Fb"
  : "0x33Bcd8bf72D594B0974beFd830a29CeC55079976";
const url = process.env.PROD ? "https://kovan.infura.io/v3/2bd0c2e1f29f4ab9b47374c6b50023c5"
  : "http://127.0.0.1:8545";

const web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(url);
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
const { toWei, numberToHex: toHex } = web3.utils;

const sendETH = async () => {
  const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(PK);
  const tx = new EthereumTx({
    from: PK,
    to: "0x8631c939359FBb8cb336532b191ED80b20287CD1",
    value: toHex(toWei(".1")),
    gas: toHex("21000"),
    nonce,
  });
  tx.sign(Buffer.from(SK, "hex"));
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"));
}
sendETH();
```

When I set PROD to false (testing on local network), it works fine. However I get that stubborn error every time I set the PROD to true (testing on Kovan).

Answer (score 2):

Hey you need to do this for testing on kovan

```
const tx = new EthereumTx({
    from: PK,
    chainId: 42, // kovan chain id
    to: "0x8631c939359FBb8cb336532b191ED80b20287CD1",
    value: toHex(toWei(".1")),
    gas: toHex("21000"),
    nonce,
  });
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm getting an "invalid sender" error now, would you happen to know any common gotchas I might be running into? Same code, just modified to incorporate your answer.

Comment: try the from address for "from" key, let tx be just an object instead of using EthereumTx
and use this

`let tx = new Tx(txObject, {

        chain: 'kovan',   // you can remove chain id from tx object

        hardfork: 'petersburg'

    })

    let key = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 'hex')

    tx.sign(key)

    let serializedTx = tx.serialize()

    let raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

    // Broadcast the transaction

    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw)`

Comment: I believe I followed your instructions correctly, but no dice... thanks for the help though!

Comment: try this https://medium.com/blockchain-musings/how-to-create-raw-transactions-in-ethereum-part-1-1df91abdba7c#:~:text=Raw%20transactions%20are%20a%20way,transactions%20outside%20the%20geth%20console.

Comment: That article does the same process I'm doing, except it assumes `require("ethereumjs-tx")` to be a class where I'm assuming `require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction` to be a class. I'm guessing this is just outdated procedure, since the post was from 2017. I also double checked my public key, and I have a balance of ETH on kovan, so it must be a valid address. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wow I'm stupid. I had the url routing to a goerli testnet on infura, but setting it back to kovan is resulting in the same error. So back to square 0.

Comment: can you upvote the answer if possible then?

Comment: I would but I don't have enough reputation yet. I'll upvote it when I am able to

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around in the source files of ethereumjs-tx, I found that the way to specify a chainId and hardfork is to add a second object to your EthereumTx constructor.

The `chainId` field takes a number (chainId) or a string (chain name), which just acts as a query to require the data necessary for that chain. This field defaults to `"mainnet"`.

The `hardfork` field works similar to the `chainId` field, but it exclusively handles strings. The default for this field is `"petersburg"`.

My solution was as follows:

```
const tx = new EthereumTx({
    from: PK,
    to: "0x8631c939359FBb8cb336532b191ED80b20287CD1",
    value: toHex(toWei(".0001")),
    gas: toHex("21000"),
    nonce,
  }, { chain: 42 });
```

A big thank you to viraj for giving his solution in the comments